# When trying to join 2 tables, linked data is not loaded In ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am starting to learn ASP.NET Core and EF, I have a MySQL test database: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PfL0.png

I read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#other-relationship-patterns but I'm not sure if I did it right.

Here is some of my code:

```
public class StoreDbContext : DbContext
{
    public StoreDbContext(DbContextOptions<StoreDbContext> options)
    : base(options) { }
    public DbSet<Product> Product => Set<Product>();
    public DbSet<Type_Product> Type_Product => Set<Type_Product>();
}
```

IStoreRepository.cs

```
public interface IStoreRepository
{
    IQueryable<Product> Product { get; }
    IQueryable<Type_Product> Type_Product { get; }
}
```

EFStoreRepository.cs

```
public class EFStoreRepository : IStoreRepository
{
    private StoreDbContext context;

    public EFStoreRepository(StoreDbContext ctx)
    {
        context = ctx;
    }

    public IQueryable<Product> Product => context.Product;
    public IQueryable<Type_Product> Type_Product => context.Type_Product;
}
```

Product.cs

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public long? productID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("type_productID")]
    public long? type_productID { get; set; }
    public virtual Type_Product? Type_Product { get; set; }
    public string name_product { get; set; } = String.Empty;
}
```

Type_Product.cs

```
public class Type_Product
{
    [Key]
    public long? type_productID { get; set; }
    public string name_type_product { get; set; } = String.Empty;
    public virtual ICollection<Product>? Product { get; set; }
}
```

HomeController.cs

```
private IStoreRepository repository;

public HomeController(IStoreRepository repo)
{
    repository = repo;
}

ViewResult Index()
{
    var t = repository.Product.Include(o => o.Type_Product).ToList();
    return View(t);
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<ClothingShop.Models.Product>

@foreach (var p in Model)
{
    <p>@p. name_product </p>        // normal
}

@foreach (var k in Model)
{
    <p>@k.Type_Product.name_type_product</p>    /error
}
```

I am getting an error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

since `TypeProduct = null`.

Is this due to the incorrect use of `.Include` in `HomeController`?

Because

```
var t = repository.Product.Include(o => o.Type_Product);
```

`Type_Product` belongs to `Product`, not `repository.Type_Product`?

Should I explicitly initialize `Type_Product` somewhere?

How to bring it to a working condition?

Comment: For starters I would recommend using [standard C# naming conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions#naming-conventions)ю

Comment: As for the issue - what SQL engine are you using? Check the generated query, maybe your setup leads to some incorrect SQL generation. Also it is quite strange to have nullable primary keys. And relation between product and product type seems to be optional, so possibly you have no product type for this product.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, as Guru Stron said, I used standard naming conventions and this solved my problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).